# How can I translate sic/xe to object code?

Tags: assembly, computer-science, object-code, sic

[image]
[image]

Above sic/xe code,

I don't understand translate process.

`105F        LDT    LENGTH`  =>   `774000`

`1056  EXIT  STX    LENGTH` =>  `134000`

I already know translate opcode and 000.

But I don't know how can I get `4`.

Please give me kind explanation.

Comment: 4 is the `x b p e` bits. This instruction is using the 12 bit displacement from the B register addressing mode, which is defined as `0 1 0 0`. `B` has been previously set to `#LENGTH` hence the offset is zero.

Comment: Then, why this instruction do not have `4`?



`0023  STA LENGTH  0F200D`

Comment: There are multiple addressing options. For that, the assembler chose to use `0 0 1 0` which is 12 bit signed displacement from PC. Note that the instructions you first asked are above address 1000 hence out of range for a 12 bit PC relative offset.

Comment: Thank you sir. I understand base-relative. But I still don't understand PC relative range. I guess the range of PCs available is 0000 < PC < 1077 ? So if we go beyond this range, we use the base-relative?

Comment: PC relative is relative to the address of the current instruction where you use it. It's just a number added to the PC.